# Function for bigrams matching

Tags: java

I have got a following function:

```
public static ArrayList<String> matchLists(ArrayList<String> ar1, ArrayList<String> ar2, ArrayList<String> ar3) {

  ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

  for (int i = 0; i < ar1.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ar2.size(); j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < ar3.size(); k++) {

        String[] s1 = ar1.get(i).split("\\s");
        String[] s2 = ar2.get(j).split("\\s");
        String[] s3 = ar3.get(k).split("\\s");

        if (s1[1].equals(s2[0]) && s2[1].equals(s3[0])) {
          result.add(s1[0] + " " + s2[0] + " " + s3[0] + " " + s3[1]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

It takes as input 3 ArrayLists of bigrams and compares them. If the second word from the first array list matches the word from the second array list then they create a sentence.

Example:

```
1st Array List: he ate
2nd Array List: ate two
3rd Array List: two apples
```

creates a sentence he ate two apples. But this function is only limited to 3 ArrayLists. I would like to make it more robust so It would accept a 2d ArrayList of strings where each single ArrayList would be a collection of bigrams and would be checking all the possible matchings from the available bigrams. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: it's not a homework. just working on some bigram matching program

Answer (score 0):

A 2D `ArrayList` of strings would be `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.  Then you just need to change your loops to loop through all of the other `ArrayLists`.  I'm not going to tell you how to do this (as this does look very much like homework) but you should be able to figure it out quite easily :)